# Locking Navicat icon to Launcher

Tags: ubuntu, navicat

I am using navicat premium on ubuntu 15.10 with Wine. To Run navicat, every day I have to run the `./start_navicat` bash file from terminal.
How can I lock it on the Launcher ? and open with only one click in future.

Answer (score 1):

Create a starter **navicat.desktop** in ~/.local/share/applications with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Navicat
Comment=Database Admin Tool
Exec=/bin/sh  "/opt/navicat/start_navicat"
Icon=/opt/navicat/navicat-premium-icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Wine;
StartupNotify=true
```

Adapt the paths to your installtion. The icon is not in the package an can be obtained [here](https://www.file-extensions.org/navicat-premium-file-extensions)